# yum remove mktemp REMOVED ALL DEPENDENCY PACKAGES

Tags: unix

I removed all the packages in CentOS by chance using yum remove mktemp removed almost all the bin packages including rpm and openssh. The terminal that I'm connected is the only one which is the gate for me. If I disconnect I can't do ssh too. Any way to roll it back and get the packages installed.? Please help!!

Comment: This is going to be way harder to fix than it's worth. I'd suggest just recovering from a backup.

Answer (score 0):

How did you manage to do that? I can't reproduce this on CentOS 6; the following error occurs (after several seconds of listing all the packages it's going to remove, which should have been a clue):

```
Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected
```

Anyway, on with the answer...

If you somehow still have `yum` on your system, and it somehow still works, you can view the history and undo the most recent transaction:

```
yum history
```

will show your most recent transactions, each with a number, and then

```
yum history undo ###
```

will undo the transaction listed.

If you don't have a working `yum` on your system, then you've damaged it beyond reasonable repair and should restore from backup.

Comment: He removed `rpm`. There's no way `yum` can fix things without `rpm`.

Comment: Oh, well, in that case it's "restore from backup" time. Somebody else who reads this in the future may be able to `undo` their own yum disaster, though.

Comment: Yeah, it's still something worth knowing. Sadly, his case is too badly screwed up.